# SQL QUERY Oracle log analysis

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a log in table that have something like this:

tablelog

```
date      |  time   | event      | program   | ordendate
20130722    070000    executing    program1    20130722
20130722    070040    end ok       program1    20130722
20130722    070100    executing    program1    20130722
20130722    070140    end ok       program1    20130722
```

I have a query

```
 select a.date || a.time as datetimeStart, 
        b.date || b.time as datetimeStop, 
        a.program, a.ordendate  
   from tablelog a, 
        tablelog b
  where a.date || a.time < b.date || b.time
    and a.event = "executing"
    and b.event = "end ok"
```

This return 3 executions but only I have 2... How can I fix this query???

Thank you!!

Comment: Why it should return 3 record? I see just 2 records that satisfy your query.

Comment: What's preventing the last event from matching the very first event in your query?

Comment: You should never store dates and timestamps in varchar columns. Why don't you using a single `timestamp` instead?

Comment: it is a system log.... i'm sory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you want to list sequential start/stops by program(?) This uses `LEAD` to do the work in a `CTE`, then just filters and orders using an outer query;

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN "event"='executing' THEN "date" || "time" END "datetimeStart",
    LEAD(CASE WHEN "event"='end ok' THEN "date" || "time" END) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY "program" ORDER BY "date","time") "datetimeStop",
    "program", "ordendate"
  FROM tablelog
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE "datetimeStart" IS NOT NULL 
  AND "datetimeStop"  IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY "datetimeStart"
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e6d7/11).

Answer (score 1):

The query that you are trying to do is best done using the analytic functions `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select dateTimeStart, dateTimeStop, program, orderdate
from (select tl.date || tl.time as datetimeStart,
             lead(tl.date || tl.time) over (partition by program order by date, time) as dateTimeStop,
             tl.*
      from tablelog tl
     ) tl
where tl.event = 'Executing';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the above will return the following 3 records :-

1. first record matched with second record
2. first record matched with fourth record
3. third record matched with fourth record.

To resolve that, try the following query (untested) :-

```
select * from
(select a.date || a.time as datetimeStart, 
        b.date || b.time as datetimeStop, 
        a.program, a.ordendate, row_number() over (partition by (a.date || a.time) order by (a.date || a.time)) rn  
   from tablelog a, 
        tablelog b
  where a.date || a.time < b.date || b.time
    and a.event = "executing"
    and b.event = "end ok")
where rn =1
```